# subset data matching two variables in another data frame

Tags: r

**Situation**

I have two data frames, `df1` and `df2`:

```
id <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)
position <- c("AA", "BB", "CC", "DD", "EE", "FF", "GG", "HH")
value <- c(100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800)
df1 <- data.frame(id, position, value)

id <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8)
position <- c("AA", "BB", "CC", "EE", "DD", "HH")
value <- c(700, 800, 900, 100, 200, 900)
df2 <- data.frame(id, position, value)
```

**Question**

I would like to select all the rows in `df1` where there is a matching `id` AND `position` in `df2`.

**Attempts**

I'm pretty sure this is quite simple but I'm struggling to find a suitable solution.

I can do this using `merge`, but I'd like to avoid having to remove columns and hard-coding variable names.

```
#this method works for this small example but I have many variables and don't want
#to write them all out when removing the unwanted ones
df3 <- merge(x=df1, y=df2, by=c("id","position"))
df3 <- df3[,-4]    #remove unused column
df3
```

I thought I could use `dplyr`, something like

```
#library(dplyr)
df3 <- filter(df1, id %in% df2$id) 
df3
```

But I'm not having much luck matching on two variables.

**Desired output**

```
  id position value.x
1  1       AA     100
2  2       BB     200
3  3       CC     300
4  8       HH     800
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`merge` could still be used quite efficiently, without the need to remove columns after merging.

```
keys <- c("id","position")
merge(df1,df2[keys],by=keys)

#  id position value
#1  1       AA   100
#2  2       BB   200
#3  3       CC   300
#4  8       HH   800
```

Comment: or just `merge(df1, df2[-3])` if OP *really* cares about keystrokes

Comment: I didn't realise you can do the `merge` this way, but looking at it it makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

You can `paste` the two columns together and `match` them:

```
    df1[match(paste(df2$id,df2$position),paste(df1$id,df1$position),nomatch=0),]
    #id position value
    #1  1       AA   100
    #2  2       BB   200
    #3  3       CC   300
    #8  8       HH   800
```

Comment: @tospig - I don't see how this gets around your issue. You would have to write out the long list of variables twice.

Comment: I guess he wanted to merge the two data.frames without using `merge`. Of course he doesn't have "to write out the long list of variables". He can just define the vector of variable names as you did. But I don't think it has anything to do with this answer.

Comment: I see the confusion; I made an error in my comment, I meant to say I don't want to have to write out all the variables that I will need to remove. So yes, I'm happy to write out the two columns I am 'merging' on. 
edited my question accordingly.